# How to tell jQuery to animate an element that is right on top of the link that triggers it?

Tags: jquery

I used this function to animate the parent element of the link:

```
            $(".user-review-toggle").toggle(function(){
                $(this).css("backgroundPosition", "0 -12px");
                $(this).closest('.user-review').animate({height:150},200);
            },function(){
                $(this).css("backgroundPosition", "0 0");
                $(this).closest('.user-review').animate({height:98},200);
            });
```

But now, what I need to do is to animate the element that sits on top of the link:

```
    <div class="user-contribution">
     <p class="user-review"> Review</p> 2. Animate this
     <a class="user-review-toggle" href="#">Read more...</a> // 1. Clicking this
```

There are many `.user-contributions` divs so the link must only animate the one that is on top of it.

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the immediately-preceding element, e.g.:

```
$(".user-review-toggle").prev().toggle(...);
//                       ^
```

`prev` returns the sibling element immediately before the reference element. In your case, since the `p` is immediately prior to the `a`, that's what you want.